# Error in parsing JSON string

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have a JSON string like:

```
{
    "circles": [{
        "center": {
            "lat": -34.59,
            "lng": 150.01999999999998
        },
        "radius": 12726.552313389808
    }, {
        "center": {
            "lat": -33.95,
            "lng": 150.29999999999995
        },
        "radius": 23875.96767618612
    }],
    "polygons": [
        [
            [{
                "lat": -34.40237742424136,
                "lng": 149.58984375
            }, {
                "lat": -34.19362958613085,
                "lng": 149.7601318359375
            }, {
                "lat": -34.3162183808074,
                "lng": 149.8809814453125
            }]
        ],
        [
            [{
                "lat": -33.85216970140739,
                "lng": 149.4744873046875
            }, {
                "lat": -33.74261277734687,
                "lng": 149.8150634765625
            }, {
                "lat": -33.85673152928874,
                "lng": 149.864501953125
            }]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I could go through the "circles" items successfully with the following code:

```
  Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(s)
  Dim lat As String = ""
  Dim lon As String = ""
  Dim rad As String = ""

  For Each msg As JObject In json("circles")                
      lat = msg("center")("lat").ToString
      lon = msg("center")("lng").ToString
      rad = msg("radius").ToString
   Next
```

But i am having a hard time trying to reiterate through the polygons objects.
Sorry for the ugly json string, first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: I swore I saw an answer to this that someone posted but the answer is gone.  Am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure but only moderators and users with at least 10k can see deleted answers. Maybe you will get lucky and someone will come along and give it to you...

Comment: I don´t understand the downvote. This is a fair question.

Comment: Can you include the code that loops through the polygons?

Comment: Looping through the polygon json is what im having trouble with.  The json is what is given by the client and therefore have no control on how they send it.

Comment: @MRaygun post the polygon's code part. Keep in mind `circles` and `polygons` are not on the same level. Use something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see it on a tree view. I mean the same code won't read those two collections.

Comment: I understand that there has to be diffent code to read the polygon section since it seems like its a list of a list of a list.  I tried, but unsuccessful, `Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(s)
  Dim lat As String = ""
  Dim lon As String = ""
  Dim rad As String = ""

  lat= json("polygons") (0)(0)              
  `